# Android: How do I scale a bitmap to fit the screen size using canvas/draw bitmap?

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I am taking an image and drawing it to the screen using canvas. I want to scale it based on the screen size.

This is what I tried, but it cuts off a large chunk of the image:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.myimage);
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, false);

Rect frameToDraw = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
RectF whereToDraw = new RectF(0, 0, width, height);

canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,frameToDraw,whereToDraw, paint);
```

I know I am doing a few things wrong, but I'm not exactly sure what. This code causes the image to exceed the size of the screen. I want it to be scaled to the size of the screen. I'll be drawing smaller images in too that I also will need to scale *according* to the size of the screen, though not to the full screen.

Comment: Were you able to figure out the solution ? If yes, please share it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Rect frameToDraw = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
RectF whereToDraw = new RectF(0, 0, width, height);
```

Take a look at the above code. Your are not scaling the picture. You are simply taking a part of the picture (in this case the whole picture) and pasting it somewhere (in this case the size of the original picture).

The width and heigth of the `frameToDraw` rectangle should be the width and height of your picture.

Comment: So the "width" and "height" variables I thought *are* my screen size. They come from Display metrics. Is that not correct?

Comment: I tried setting my bitmap to scale to a specific size, and the "frametodraw" I see to the exact same size, then set the where to draw to the height and width I grab from Display metrics, but I'm still seeing only a portion of the image being grabbed

Comment: Scratch that. I think I figured it out. Let me try something else and get back to this.

Comment: I'm sorry mate, I made a mistake. Check my answer again.

Answer (score 2):

dont need creat scale bitmap, instead:

```
Bitmap frameBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameBufferWidth,frameBufferHeight, Config.RGB_565);
```

`frameBufferWidth` and `frameBufferHeight` are the sizes that you want to make your app base on those(for example **480*800**)

then simply add this code:

```
Rect dstRect = new Rect();
canvas.getClipBounds(dstRect); // get canvas size base screen size
canvas.drawBitmap(framebuffer, null, dstRect, null);
```

it draw your final bitmap according to screen size

Answer (score 1):

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

If you get your width and height like this, you aren't going to take the size of any toolbar/status bar/navigation bar into account.

If you are coding an app that has a `View`, inflate a layout with an `ImageView` that is full size (i.e. `match_parent`), then use the `scaleType` to scale/fit/crop the image how you want.

Comment: I actually need to do it programmatically, without using an imageview

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding. Are you saying just pull the scaling information from an empty imageview?

Comment: Okay, let's say you're trying to do more than just pop an image on the screen.  If I were doing this, I would have a custom `View` subclass and override `onDraw` to do the drawing to the canvas.  That way I could use the size of the view for width and height.  I've learned you have to override `onLayout` for initializing things because that's the point when you know the view's size.